# Extension point need to register?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a new extension point. After creating the extension point and trying to get the configuration elements of the newly created extension point, it always giving me the empty results. Do I need to configure the newly created extension point anywhere in order to make it work?

I followed the same steps that are mentioned in the Vogella tutorial site.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html#tutorialextensionpoint_usingextension

Everything I have followed according to the above tutorial except the portion of getting:

```java
IConfigurationElement[] config =
        registry.getConfigurationElementsFor(IGREETER_ID);
```

Because I am not using any injection. I added the code in start() method of `Activator` . Below is the code:

```java
IExtensionRegistry extensionRegistry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
IExtensionPoint extensionPoint = extensionRegistry.getExtensionPoint(IGREETER_ID);
IConfigurationElement[] configurationElements = extensionPoint.getConfigurationElements();
```

I am using Eclipse Mars.

Comment: The Activator start method does not run until something else in the plugin runs - so is it actually being run?

Comment: Yes. It is running. how I have done is, for testing purpose,I created a rcp application. Inside the rcp application, I created a extension point. And that extension point I tried to access. So while debuggin I found that  IConfigurationElement[]  giving empty.

Comment: You are going to have to show us the extension point definition and the extension point usage as there is no way to know what is wrong from what you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the ID. If you set the ID in the ExtensionPoint definition to "myid" you need to access it in the getExtensionPoint-method by concatenating the plug-in ID with the point ID.

Edit: If you have already made sure that the ID is correct and your extension is still not found, the reason then might be, that the bundle, which makes the extension to your extension point, is not part of the bundles, which are loaded when you start your application.